How large would an orbital habitat need to be to diffuse light like an atmosphere
The sky is blue during the day due to the Rayleigh effect scattering the light as it passes through the air. Assuming it's possible at all, in a glass domed orbital habitat how large would it have to be for the contained atmosphere to scatter the light in the same or similar way?

Useful little piece of data: half of the mass of Earth's atmosphere lies in the first 5.5 km (3.1 miles) altitude.

This question would probably get better answers on Physics SE, although you'll need to show an attempt to solve the problem yourself and change from your specific question to a question about the generalized physics involved (what is the relationship between dome size and the color of the sky) to avoid closure.

This is more straight-forward than you might think. If you want the intensity of the blue you see in Earth's sky, you need the quantity and density of atmosphere found between the surface and Space (but not necessarily the distance, @AlexP's right). But be careful of what you ask for, that's still a very large habitat. And the smaller the habitat, the more its orientation to a star would affect seeing the effect. And it's worth noting that as atmospheric pressure increases, the color darkens and shifts.

Is it important that it’s specifically the atmosphere causing that, or do you just want a blue sky? In the latter case, why not just have the orbital habitat’s dome have built-in blue light emitters/floodlights/screens that make it look like it’s blue? We’re already talking about immensely-advanced technology…

First, let us assume that the Earth is flat and the sun is infinitely far away. Your airless planet is also flat, has no atmosphere, and has a dome sitting on it.
Every cyan sky-glow photon indexed $i$ that reached your retina was initially parallel and scattered on its $n_i$th interaction with an air molecule.
On average, they scattered after $\bar n$ interactions.
Number of interactions is directly proportionate to number density and path length. Number density is close enough to directly proportionate to pressure for back-of-envelope math to assume that it is. So, we can throw out the calculus of an infinite height infinitely rarified atmosphere and replace the whole (flat) atmosphere with a roughly 10km tall 1 atm pressurized air brick sitting on top of our nice flat Earth.
(Note: this approximation won't work if we want to know what a person at a higher altitude will see, it's just for people near sea level.)
Then $\bar n$ corresponds to $\bar x$, the average path length through the air before the photon that reached your eye scattered.
So, here is our problem:
On average, a cyan photon that scattered into your eye scattered after passing from an altitude of $10km$ to an altitude of $10km - \bar x$. Blue sky is what it looks like when something like that happens.
We can increase the pressure $P$ in the dome, or in a cavity between the dome and the outside world, in order to decrease $\bar x$ according to $\bar x_b / \bar x_a = P_a / P_b$
But your dome is a dome, and its starting altitude changes with its distance from the center.
Consequently, no matter how much we pressurize the dome or how big you make it you will never get a full blue sky effect, even sitting at the center (and especially not sitting at the edge), unless we make the dome so big (tens of kilometers tall, many tens of kilometers wide) that we can approximate that the lid of the dome is also flat.
Solution: make the lid of the dome actually flat. That is to say: don't live in an upside down bowl, live in a double-decker cake pan, and highly pressurize the upper cake pan.
This is a terrible idea from a safety and cost perspective, but aesthetics demands it!
(A cheaper and less suicidal solution would be to paint the dome cyan and pipe sunlight inside with a system of mirrors. You can even project it along a partial arc of the artificial sky so that the light changes with the hour.)

The question also has the word "similar" in it, so if the center of your dome would have its sky sphere "something-blue" if the dome is high enough or has enough gas inside, that could say "good enough" for the question. So I'd say "10 km somewhat-flat with a little extra pressure" would do as a napkin answer.

Thanks for the detailed comment. This is exactly the kind of compromise I enjoy for aesthetics. Who says the architects don't like to live on the edge
